# What is the correct approach to find delta between two files

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have files placed in Google Storage Bucket on a daily basis, I am trying to find the correct the approach in Google Cloud Dataflow to find the delta between two text files (Today's file and yesterday's file).  I am not seeing any out of the box function in the data flow API to find the delta between two PCollection. Do we have out API support for finding the delta or we should write PTransform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing API for finding the difference between two PCollections. Each PCollection represents a possibly unbounded stream of unordered, timestamped events. The difference between two unbounded streams is not well defined.

Given these are coming from files, you should be able to write something to do this. For instance, you could key by the content of the lines, then perform a CoGroupByKey looking for keys that are in the left file and not the right.